# RTNETLINK answers: Connection timed out

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, networkmanager

I installed arch and everything works fine except for the wifi.

When I try to bring the interface up with ip link I get the following answer:

```
# ip link set wlp3s0 up
RTNETLINK answers: Connection timed out
```

the devices don't seem to be blocked

```
 rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

`systemctl status NetworkManager` tells me this:

```
 <error> [1643663906.2369] device (wlp3s0): Couldn't initialize supplicant interface: Timeout was reached
```